# Sencha Touch: Change text color of a component

Tags: css, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.3, sencha-touch-theming

I have a simple View (Container) containing a component. Content is added to this component using `Ext.getCmp('foo').setHtml('bar');`

I want now to change the text color of the component "foo". Using the style-property works fine, but only as long as `styleHtmlContent` is set to `false`.

How can I change the text color but still setting `styleHtmlContent` to `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the property `styleHtmlCls` to `<myClass>` on the specific component was the trick! Doing so I was able to create an custom css file which contains `<myClass>` where the custom color is specified...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Ext.Component#addCls(String)` method to add some CSS class to your component.

Once you `bar` class is declared in your css file with your text styling, just do :

```
Ext.getCmp('foo').addCls('bar');
```

That way, you will simply add some css styling to your component and not override them.

Link to documentation : http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-addCls